# "Impossible" to install Ralink rt5370 driver on Xubuntu 14.10

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb-drive, ralink

I really need help to install this driver on Xubuntu 14.10. I couldn't get my WiFi USB network dongle (elmak SAVIO CL-63) which came with a CD-ROM containing the drive for chipset RT5370 for Linux.

I have the latest Linux headers and when I run the `lsusb` command the result is:

```
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
```

I ran the command `sudo make clean` and after `sudo make && make install` and the end of compilation is:

```
 CC [M]  /home/vladimir/2011_0225_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.1_DPO/os/linux/../../sta/wpa.o
  CC [M]  /home/vladimir/2011_0225_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.1_DPO/os/linux/../../sta/ags.o
  CC [M]  /home/vladimir/2011_0225_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.1_DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o
/home/vladimir/2011_0225_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.1_DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPIoctlShow’:
/home/vladimir/2011_0225_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.1_DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:4935:85: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
             snprintf(extra, size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, __TIME__ );
                                                                                     ^
/home/vladimir/2011_0225_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.1_DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:4935:95: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
             snprintf(extra, size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, __TIME__ );
                                                                                               ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '/home/vladimir/2011_0225_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.1_DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/vladimir/2011_0225_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.1_DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o] Error 1
Makefile:1345: recipe for target '_module_/home/vladimir/2011_0225_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.1_DPO/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/vladimir/2011_0225_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.1_DPO/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-28-generic'
Makefile:356: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

So I couldn't install the driver. I added to `blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist rt2x00usb
blacklist rt2x00lib
blacklist rt2800usb
```

and a directory `/etc/Wireless/RT2870STA$/RT2870STA.dat` was created

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: You will never get this 2011-era driver to compile on the relatively new 3.16.0-xx kernel. The driver for the device, rt2800usb, is present in 14.10 by default. If it isn't working as expected, we ought to address that issue instead of installing an _older_ driver suite. What is not working?

Comment: @chili555: We were both editing the same post...  :( Re-editing...

Comment: :)  Done!  (and disappearing now that I know that the god of WiFi is attending to this himself!)  ;-)

Comment: As if driver for this device is already present in 14.10, WHY when I connect the device nothing happen, the wifi adapter is not working, how to get it working? what is missing?

Comment: It will not create a wireless interface if the driver is blacklisted. With the device inserted, please run: sudo modprobe rt2800usb. Does the interface start? iwconfig.

Comment: i ran modprobe and result is:

Comment: lo       no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan1     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

Comment: it looks that is wlan1 is this adapter, and now what to do?

Comment: @chili555 i clicked the icon on system tray for network manager and it shows this wi-fi connection(Ralink 802.11 n WLAN) and the status is disconnected, I cannot click on that because is disable to click i cannot select that. How to enable this connection?

Comment: We need more information in order to diagnose your problem. Please run the wireless_script as outlined here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108 As the result is lengthy, please post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com. Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 http://paste.ubuntu.com/9672987/ is the link of the result of the script, thanks

Comment: You have an internal wireless device that is working and connected. Why did you need to get a USB and use it instead? We may need to disable the internal.

Comment: @chili555 Yes I have internal wireless card that's working, BUT this internal wireless card has wick range of the internal antenna, I cannot connect from my living room, I only connect where the router is. should I disable this to get working the USB one? how I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step I suggest is to blacklist the driver for the internal card so that the driver suites don't interfere. From a terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist ath5k"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r ath5k
exit
```

It may take a reboot. If this is ineffective, I will edit this answer with further steps.

Comment: I will try, but I switched of wifi on my laptop and I can not switch it on again this is terrible i will find out

Comment: What does this tell us? rfkill list all Thanks.

Comment: rfkill list: 0: phy: Wireless LAN  Soft blocked: no  Hard Block: no   , What to do? I have a hardware switch that doesn't work.

Comment: May I see another wireless_script as above, please?

Comment: I found out what happened and now it is working again. now i'm going to do your first step and remove ath5k driver.

Comment: it's done and rebooted now i don't have wifi connection and when i click on network manager icon on system tray i can't see (Ralink 802.11 n WLAN) anymore, what's next?

Comment: May I see another wireless_script as above, please?

Comment: FINALLY I have a working dongle (ralink 802.11 n WLAN), I have appreciated your help, i read a configuration set on ubuntu documentation about USB network adapter Ralink rt5370 and I edit on /etc/udev/rules.d and added new rules named 95-rt5370-usb.rules as described on this documentation. many thanks.